# Failed to call javascript function using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having trouble calling a javascript function from a jQuery statement. Seems the jQuery inside the javascript function is not working. Is there any syntax error?

The code worked as this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // init the state from the input
    $(".image-checkbox").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().attr("checked")) {
            $(this).addClass('image-checkbox-checked');
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('image-checkbox-checked');
        }
    });

    // sync the state to the input
    $(".image-checkbox").on("click", function (e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('image-checkbox-checked')) {
            $(this).removeClass('image-checkbox-checked');
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().removeAttr("checked");
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('image-checkbox-checked');
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().attr("checked", "checked");
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The structure is changed because I need more functions inside the filterImage function, and the statement inside the bracket failed to run properly.

```
$(".image-checkbox").on("click", function(e) {
        filterImage();
    });

function filterImage() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('image-checkbox-checked')) {
            $(this).removeClass('image-checkbox-checked');
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().removeAttr("checked");
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('image-checkbox-checked');
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: wrap the `$(document).ready(function() {` around your event handler and remove it from the function

Comment: Any errors in your console? is the function or the click event itself executed?

Comment: @empiric, Thanks for your prompt reply! From what I saw, the statement inside the if-else bracket is not running properly, and thus it always go into the else part.

Comment: Then you ran into a problem with your function scope regarding `this`, which will not refer to the clicked element but to the `window` object

Comment: @empiric, I see what you mean. I'm new to javascript and jQuery, so I need to find another way to select the clicked element?

Comment: Have a look Santis answer, that should help you

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant to do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".image-checkbox").on("click", function() {
        filterImage(this);
    });
});

function filterImage(e) {
    var $e = $(e);
    if ($e.hasClass('image-checkbox-checked')) {
        $e.removeClass('image-checkbox-checked');
        $e.find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().removeAttr("checked");
    } else {
        $e.addClass('image-checkbox-checked');
        $e.find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().attr("checked", "checked");
    }
}
```

Notice that I've moved your `ready` event around the click event, instead of within the function.

Additionally, your use of `$(this)` would not have worked, because you were not passing the clicked element to the function. I've remedied this and casted the clicked element as `$e` in your `filterImage()` function.

Comment: This is a great answer. Note that $(document).ready() is an event which will be fired when the document is ready (more or less when the page opens). It should not be put inside a function.

Comment: You explicitly not need to check if an element contains a class if you are planning to remove it.

Comment: Sure, if the *only* thing you plan on doing is removing it. But the `hasClass` in the function above acts as a substitute for `:checked` - it's the primary conditional operator of the entire function.

Comment: Agreed. Didn't see the later part. You can also call the function directly instead of invoking it explicitly inside the click event. $(".image-checkbox").on("click", filterImage); and access the element via 'this'

Comment: This is correct, however I personally prefer anonymous functions. I find them more readable and they allow you to add parameters in the event things change moving forward.